# Why does SQL JOIN allow duplicates but IN does not

Tags: t-sql, sybase

Example scenario:

TABLE_A contains a column called ID and also contains duplicate rows. There is another table called ID_TABLE that contains IDs. Assuming no duplicates in ID_TABLE -

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN ID_TABLE ON ID_TABLE.ID = TABLE_A.ID
```

There will be duplicates in the result set. However, if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE TABLE_A.ID IN (SELECT ID_TABLE.ID FROM ID_TABLE)
```

There will not be any duplicates in the result set.

Does anyone know why the `JOIN` clause allows duplicates while the `IN` clause does not? I had thought they did the same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it's allowing duplicates. By joining the two tables, you are creating a product from table 1 and table 2, so if TABLE_A has two records for ID=1 and ID_Table has 1 record, the resulting product is two records. Using IN doesn't cause a multiplication of records, even if the value is listed in the IN clause multiple times as you are only getting the unique records matching the values within the IN clause.

Comment: I have read an article (can't find it anymore) that, in terms of efficiency, `IN` and `JOIN` are the same. Would you be able to comment on this?

Comment: The answer to that depends on a variety of circumstances. When in doubt, test. Personally, I've found JOINs faster in 1-to-1 relationships against a sub-select.